# Swift Custom UIView class - main thread issue in initializer

Tags: swift, class, grand-central-dispatch, toast, initializer

I am using a fairly simple "Toast" class that works - but setting up the initializers
requires the main thread - I would like to deport the main thread code to the class - is this possible ?

Current error when not forced to main thread:

[image]

I have tried a few different things, obviously wrapping the line with a dispatchQueue.main.async isn't possible.

The Init code in my project :

[image]

as text :

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            let toast = ToastView(
                title: "Pas de nouvelles données",
                titleFont: .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular),
        
                onTap: { print("Tapped!") }
            )
             
                toast.show()
       }
```

The GitHub repository for the toast code :
https://github.com/PhilippeWeidmann/NotificationToast

Anybody have any pointers to how I should approach this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code as text and not image. Also, are you initialising object from background thread? You need to show more clear code.

Comment: Just put tost.show() function on the main theread.

Comment: Thanks ... that works in my project , but I would like to not have to put it in the main thread within my code, I would like to modify the Toast class to handle the main thread part of things ... does that make sense ? Thanks :)

Comment: No. Modifying library does not make sense.

Comment: Agree with Raja, you should put main thread on your code. If you want to modify Toast library, probably just make a fork and point the pod to correct git source.

Answer (score 1):

Changing/ modify code inside the library is not a good way. You can simply add an issue or send PR for improvement to the library owner/developer.

But you can create one more function and show the alert view on the main thread if it not in the main thread.

Here is the extension part

```
extension ToastView {
    static func show(title: String, titleFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular),
                     subtitle: String? = nil, subtitleFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: .light),
                     icon: UIImage? = nil, iconSpacing: CGFloat = 16, onTap: (() -> ())? = nil) {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            ToastView(title: title, titleFont: titleFont, onTap:onTap).show()
            
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                ToastView(title: title, titleFont: titleFont, onTap:onTap).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (No matter if bellow code is inside the main queue or not)

```
ToastView.show(
                title: "Pas de nouvelles données",
                titleFont: .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular),
                onTap: { print("Tapped!") }
            )
```